# How to properly select elements to tag manually for building training and test sets?

Tags: subset

I have to select a subset (short texts like comments and twitter posts) out of a huge population to tag them manually for building a sentiment analysis training and test set. How should I select these elements?

A naive approach would be a random selection, but some texts are very short, do not contain real words or do not contain a lot of information (e.g. `blaaabla`, `!!!` or `Berlin`). So selecting them would be a waste of money, or wouldn't it? Should I use constraints (e.g., min/max length, number of words, user votes) or would you even suggest some kind of entropy-criteria for selection?